# How to run local bash script on remote server using php

Tags: php, bash, ssh

I store bash script as a string in db and I need to call it on user demand. Script should be executed on remote machine from php level. I found the following topics:

Two topics about ssh connection and calling remote script:

1. [How to use SSH to run a shell script on a remote machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine)
2. https://serverfault.com/questions/241588/how-to-automate-ssh-login-with-password

And two ways to use it in php:

1. [Run Bash Command from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052162/run-bash-command-from-php)
2. [get result from ssh2_exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086474/get-result-from-ssh2-exec) ,
   http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php

I tried to use the following code in my symfony2 application:

First attempt:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('IP_ADDRESS', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'user', 'password');
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, "'bash -s' < ".$script);
stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
$stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
$output = stream_get_contents($stream_out);
//result => output = empty string
```

Second:

```
$old_path = getcwd();
chdir('/path_to_script_directory');
$output = shell_exec("ssh user@server 'bash -s' < test");
chdir($old_path);

or

$old_path = getcwd();
chdir('/path_to_script_directory');
$output = shell_exec("ssh user@server 'bash -s' < ".$script);
chdir($old_path);
//result => output = null
```

As in examples above I tried two cases with "test" script and string script ($script variable). Second option is preffered by me. Both cases contains simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash

ifconfig
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What was the results of your attempts? What errors/issues were encountered?

Comment: i wrote results in comment "//" after both examples

Comment: Can you confirm whether your SSH connections were successful by checking the authentication log on the remote server?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a project that will give you a real bash shell on a remote server: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS

Install and run the following commands:

```
//login to the remote server and get a shell:

$shellObj       = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getRemoteHost('ip_address')->setConnectionDetail('username', 'password')->getShell();

//rather than executing your script, just run the command:

$returnData = $shellObj->exeCmd("ifconfig");

echo $returnData; //string containing the interface config of the remote server.
```