# PHP: SSH connection and python script execution

Tags: php, python, ssh

I have my front end with a button, this button talks to backend. 
The backend is starting a remote script :

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$connection = ssh2_connect('192.168.56.180', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'root', 'password');
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'python /WATSON/APP/test/testlistrbk.py');
stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
$stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
echo $stream_out_contente;
fwrite($myfile, $stream_out);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

I have 2 issues , First one, php should wait the python script to finish as it said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086474/get-result-from-ssh2-exec) but it does not.

Second one, It gives me the following :

> PHP Warning:  fwrite() expects parameter 2 to be string, resource given in /var/www/html/WEBAPP/wa_start.php on line 41

Comment: put output of `var_dump($stream_out);` before fwrite here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `stream_get_contents(stream_out);`

In your code `$stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);` this will return `resource` not string output. Try this code.

```
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

$connection = ssh2_connect('192.168.56.180', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'root', 'password');
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'python /WATSON/APP/test/testlistrbk.py');

stream_set_blocking($stream, true);

$outputStream = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
$errorStream = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR);

echo "Output: " . stream_get_contents($outputStream);
echo "Error: " . stream_get_contents($errorStream);

fwrite($myfile, $outputStream.$errorStream);
fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: @MouIdri Please check `$stream_out` will be received from `$stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);`

Comment: @Mouldri you just need to replace last three lines of your code with my code.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see the missing $.. I changed it and I do not have error message any more,. But behavior is very strange, because nothing is written to file ( I chmoded 0777, so it is not a rights issue ).

Comment: @MouIdri  i am updating my post then you can check

Comment: @MouIdri Try this code and check whether it is working fine or not  You can refer to this as well http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php#99089