# Shutdown through ssh not working properly

Tags: php, ssh, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

so here is my problem: 
I have a pc that i use mainly through ssh and i recently created a telegram bot to quickly perform those commands used more frequently.

It works fine except for the shutdown command.

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('www.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'user', 'mypass');
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'netstat | grep ESTABLISHED || shutdown -P now');
```

I use this code since i need to verify nobody else (my brother) is connected to the pc before shutting it down, but it looks like that regardless the output of `netstat | grep ESTABLISHED` the code `|| shutdown -P now` is always gettin executed.

I always used such a code through ssh to verify the connection and it has always work'd fine. how can i have `|| shutdown -P now` part executed only if the output of `netstat | grep ESTABLISHED`is empty?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently,  `ssh2_exec` can't execute several commands joined by operators. In your case it looks like it just parses the command and executes the last one. Or it just executes all the command one by one.
What you can do, is to split your commands.

How to get the result of the `ssh2_exec` command:

[[get result from ssh2_exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086474/get-result-from-ssh2-exec][1])

So when you get the result you can process it and run another **ssh2_command** for shutting down.

Comment: I figured out now to solve this. I created in the remote machine a bash file with an if structure and i call It from ssh. This worked fine for me